# Can a foreign key reference the primary key in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm creating a comment system under a post article. I have one table for comments with ID, post_id, user_id, text and comment_id column. So my thinking is, that when I add a comment under some post, the comment_id will be set to null, but if I comment another comment, the comment_id will be set to ID of the comment ID I'm commenting, which leads me to my question: is it possible to have foreign key that references the ID in the same table or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> *Can a foreign key reference the primary key in the same table?*

Yes, it is possible:

```
CREATE TABLE comments(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  comment_id INT REFERENCES comments(id)
  -- other columns
)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1627155dfa6269b0ef9723453179429f)**